# how to change app theme through downloading resources of zip format?

Tags: android, themes, skin

I want to change app theme through downloading resources, the resources is a zip file containing folders like color, drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi. how can I do this?

Comment: Please post the code till you have done

Comment: sorry, I have no idea present